# How to decode DCE RPC stub data in WireShark

Tags: wireshark, rpc, dcom

I need to compare connection session of 2 OPC DA clients connecting to a remote server. Under the hood they uses DCOM and DCE RPC. Fortunately, WireShark provides `dcerpc` dissector, but it doesn't decode stub data.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it *can*. NDR (the data format used by DCE RPC) is not "self-describing" – there's nothing in the payload that would distinguish an int32 from a float from a uint8[4]. This means Wireshark needs a specific sub-dissector for *each interface* that it needs to dissect (e.g. it has individual dissectors for the various Active Directory MS-RPC interfaces), recognizing them by looking at the UUID in the 'Bind' packet.

In this case it seems that although Wireshark has a partial dissector for IOXIDResolver ([packet-dcom-oxid.c](https://github.com/wireshark/wireshark/blob/master/epan/dissectors/packet-dcom-oxid.c#L265)), it only supports dissecting the *response* of RPC opnum 5 (apparently 'ServerAlive2') but not the request, so it leaves the remaining payload as raw data.